# How to query list of intervals with Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I need to create time slot with a duration between two timestamps.

```
SELECT t::time as appointmenttime
    FROM generate_series(
       timestamp  '2016-11-09 08:00 AM',
       timestamp  '2016-11-09 03:00 PM',
       INTERVAL '10 minutes'
    ) t ;
```

I tried this query in native query.

```
  String sql = "SELECT t::time as appointmenttime "
      + "    FROM generate_series(timestamp  :startTime,timestamp  :endTime, INTERVAL :duration ) t  ";

  NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
  nativeQuery.setParameter("startTime", "09:00:00");
  nativeQuery.setParameter("endTime", "18:00:00");
  nativeQuery.setParameter("duration", "10");
```

But in the console I got an issue:

```
SELECT t:time as appointmenttime FROM generate_series(timestamp  ?,timestamp  ?, INTERVAL ? ) t
```

How to create this query in Native query.(Why one : is missing?) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with JPA, but as a native query is supposed to be "plain" JDBC I'll try nevertheless:

In the parametrized SQL you do not need the `timestamp` keyword. It is only needed if followed by a string constant. Building an interval from a parameter also doesn't work by prefixing the `interval` keyword.

The following should work:

```
SELECT t::time as appointmenttime 
FROM generate_series(:startTime, :endTime, make_interval(mins => :duration) t
```

If JPA chokes on the `=>` operator, you will need to pass positional parameters:

```
make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, :duration)
```

---

Note that your Java code will need to pass a valid timestamp value, not a time or string value. I assume that should be an instance of `LocalDateTime` or maybe `OffsetDateTime` - I don't expect a string value for a time to work here (but again I don't know what JPA makes of that)

Answer (score 0):

At this time the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has no way of setting a value to interval. Using `timestamp ?` or `interval ?` is a syntax error.

Normally the syntax you want would end-up something like this:

```
SELECT t:time as appointmenttime FROM generate_series(?,?, ? ) t
```

With the first two parameters being set to timestamp when `setTimestamp` is called on the `PreparedStatement`. However I very recently traces through the PGJDBC driver's code to find out if it's supported, and it in fact cannot ever be invoked to set an `interval` value, as it is an unfinished feature. What you can do instead is validate your interval string manually and insert it literally in your query:

```
String validInterval = SomeUtil.toSqlInterval(duration);
String sql = "SELECT t::time as appointmenttime "
  + "    FROM generate_series(:startTime , :endTime, INTERVAL '" + validInterval + "' ) t  ";
```

PostgreSQL supports the ISO-8601 interval format, so if you're using a `java.time.Duration` object, you can just call `toString()` on it, instead of writing a syntax validation utility.